# Build failing with Amazon ProfileCredentialsProvider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, credentials

```
   //   this.s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        this.s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
```

If I uncomment the first line, my project build is failing saying that it doesn't recognise the package ( com.amazonaws.auth.profile) and that the it encountered an error at ProfileCredentialsProvider().

But if I use the second line, everything is ok. Why does that happen?

Comment: Did you try importing it at the top? Like *import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;*

Comment: Yes, the import works and it is shown as imported.